# Tikz picture: labels next to the nodes to be in a specific format

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels

I need the labels next to the nodes to be smaller and green color.
I wasn't able to modify it.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\tikzset{block/.style={
        font=\sffamily,
        draw=black,
        thin,
        fill=white!50,
        rectangle split,
        rectangle split horizontal,
        rectangle split parts=#1,
        outer sep=0pt},
        }

\begin{document}
    
\def\lvld{1.2}                  % Choose level distance
\pgfmathsetmacro\shft{-6*\lvld} % Calculate the yshift for the green tree
    
\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=\lvld cm,
                        level 1/.style={sibling distance=4cm},
                        level 2/.style={sibling distance=3cm},
                        level 3/.style={sibling distance=2cm},
                        level 3/.style={sibling distance=1.3cm},
                        edgedown/.style={edge from parent/.style={draw=black,thick,-latex}}%,
                        %edgeup/.style={edge from parent/.style={draw=green!50!black,thick,latex-}}
                        ]
        \node[block=1][label=right:{(0,0)}] (A) {(16,3)}
            [grow=down,edgedown]
            child {node[block=1][label=right:{(0,0)}] (B1) {(12,44)}
                child {node[block=1][label=right:{(0,0)}] (C1) {(18,5)}
                    child {node[block=1][label=left:{(0,0)}] (D1) {(24,3)}
                        child {node[block=1][label=right:{(0,0)}] (E1) {(10,7)}}}
                    child {node[block=1][label=right:{(0,0)}] (D2) {(3,20)}}
                    }
                                }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Add a style for your labels. For instance, every label/.style={font=\scriptsize, text=green}.

Answer (score 1):

You could change the `every label` style to however you want your labels to look like:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\tikzset{block/.style={
        font=\sffamily,
        draw=black,
        thin,
        fill=white!50,
        rectangle split,
        rectangle split horizontal,
        rectangle split parts=#1,
        outer sep=0pt},
        }

\begin{document}
    
\def\lvld{1.2}                  % Choose level distance
\pgfmathsetmacro\shft{-6*\lvld} % Calculate the yshift for the green tree
    
\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=\lvld cm,
                        level 1/.style={sibling distance=4cm},
                        level 2/.style={sibling distance=3cm},
                        level 3/.style={sibling distance=2cm},
                        level 3/.style={sibling distance=1.3cm},
                        edgedown/.style={edge from parent/.style={draw=black,thick,-latex}},
                        every label/.style={green,font=\tiny}
                        %edgeup/.style={edge from parent/.style={draw=green!50!black,thick,latex-}}
                        ]
        \node[block=1][label=right:{(0,0)}] (A) {(16,3)}
            [grow=down,edgedown]
            child {node[block=1][label=right:{(0,0)}] (B1) {(12,44)}
                child {node[block=1][label=right:{(0,0)}] (C1) {(18,5)}
                    child {node[block=1][label=left:{(0,0)}] (D1) {(24,3)}
                        child {node[block=1][label=right:{(0,0)}] (E1) {(10,7)}}}
                    child {node[block=1][label={right:{(0,0)}}] (D2) {(3,20)}}
                    }
                                };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: faster than me !

Comment: @JeT By seconds, not even a whole minute :)

Comment: @JeT Your `\scriptsize` probably took too much time to type, `\tiny` is so much shorter :)